# make select-up select whole line

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I use `shift-up` and `shift-down` to select up and down in VS Code.

Here is how it looks:

[image: select up]

However, I would like the whole line to be selected when I select up/down. Now it only selects parts of the line.

`cmd-l` does exactly what I want but it only selects down.

Answer (score 0):

Since selecting the whole line like you want is by having the cursor on the left, you can always do **SHIFT + HOME** to select your line until you're on the left side, and then **SHIFT + UP** and **SHIFT + DOWN** like you're actually doing.

Comment: I'd rather not `shift+home`

Comment: I saw you edited to include ctrl+L, I wanted to point that^^ Then the easiest solution: install the extension "Better Line Select": ctrl+L downward, ctrl+shift+L upward!

Comment: yeah, sorry, I should have mentioned that! "Better Line Select" is very close but it does not let me deselect, I will check out the code and maybe fork it.